# Installing the apk from sd card

Tags: android, sd-card, mobile-application

I want to make an android application which should be installfrom sd card. i means as the sd card inserted in mobile  it should prompt for installing my application. (ex: As soon as we put the tata photon or any other modem in to the system it prompt user to install the application)If i am right it is possible. so please guide me for the same. Please give the code as well.
thanks in advance :-)

Answer (score 4):

> If i am right it is possible

You are incorrect.

It is possible for an already-installed Android app to monitor changes in external storage and perhaps auto-install an APK. It is not possible for an uninstalled APK alone to do this, and approximately zero Android devices out of nearly one billion have this capability built in.

Answer (score 0):

You can make a broadcast receiver which will fire when memory card will inserted.Just capture this event you can do what you want.

Comment: can you please give me the code for that.? i searched for it but did not find.